# Регулярное выражение для поиска скобок

Tags: javascript, php, регулярные-выражения

В коде есть вызовы функций, какое нужно регулярное выражение, чтобы найти все подобные строки

```
(4, 7)
(a, b)
```

То есть скобочки, где перечислены две любые переменные через запятую

Comment: Не факт, что такое вообще возможно одной регуляркой, потому что можно попасть `"(a, b)"` на такую строку. Можно попробовать сначала найти и исключить все строки, потом уже искать вызовы...

Comment: У вас в скобках не везде переменные, например, 4 и 7 это константы (скалярные величины). Пожалуйста, приведите ваш нерабочий код и требования к регулярному выражению, чтобы можно было понять, что у вас не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Шаблон для поиска:

```
^\(.\h*,\h*.\)$
```

Будет искать то что true:

```
(4, 7) - true
(7, a) - true
 (a, b) - false
(4, 71) - false
(aa, b) - false
(4,7) - true
(a,b) - true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\([a-zA-Z0-9]*,[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)
```

если внутри скобок один символ, то `*` можно убрать

Comment: находит все выражения через , скобки не учитывает

Comment: @АлександрКиселев у автора ответа, регулярное выражение не было отформатировано из-за чего редактор ответов не отобразил экраны и символ `*`.